# HiddenField empty and Viewstate value null on Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, popup, devexpress, viewstate, hidden-field

This issue started when trying to get a DevExpress `ASPxPopupControl` to show after pressing a button. Using `popup.ShowOnPageLoad = true;` didn't seem to suffice, checking the value on `Page_Load` shows it reverts to `false`, even though the code on the server definitely executed.

So I decided to have a variable that reads from and writes to the `ViewState` so it persists. I then had the variable:

```
bool ShowPopup
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["ShowPopup"] == null)
            return false;
        return (bool)ViewState["ShowPopup"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["ShowPopup"] = value;
    }
}
```

Which was called on the button press by simply `ShowPopup = true`. When using `popup.ShowOnPageLoad = ShowPopup;` in `Page_Load`, `ViewState["ShowPopup"]` is `null` and therefore it returns `false`.

I then tried to use a `HiddenField`. So I changed `ShowPopup` to:

```
bool ShowPopup
{
    get
    {
        return hfShowPopup.Value != "" && hfShowPopup.Value.ToLower() != "false";
    }
    set
    {
        hfShowPopup.Value = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Again using `ShowPopup = true` on button click, when `ShowPopup` is read in `Page_Load` its value is `""` and again therefore `ShowPopup` is `false`.

I then tried to set the `HiddenField` directly via `hfShowPopup.Value = "true";` and using

```
popupDuplicatePlayer.ShowOnPageLoad = hfShowPopup.Value != "" && hfShowPopup.Value.ToLower() != "false";
```

in `Page_Load`, but again `hfShowPopup.Value` is empty.

I have used a number of other variables reading from/writing to the `ViewState` in the same page and they work fine. I know that `ViewState` and `HiddenField` might not exist early in the page life cycle but there are being used in `Page_Load` and so should be fine? I also tried to access them in `Page_LoadComplete` with the same issues. There are no `UpdatePanel`s on the page so this isn't an issue, is there any other reason for this?

I would assume that the issue with the `ViewState`, `HiddenField` *AND* the `ShowOnPageLoad` being set directly are related?

Comment: What's your markup for hidden field?

Comment: The hidden field is the simple asp.net control `<asp:HiddenField ID="hfShowPopup" runat="server" />` which renders as `<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfShowPopup" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hfShowPopup" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather silly mistake from me. In the button press I redirected to the current page, rather than allowing the post back. Therefore the values are lost on `Page_Load`. Very silly, but I figured it out anyway.